# "Please Wait" mask goes behind webdialogwindow popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

We have a Javascript div shown on PostBack on page to show a "Please wait" indicator in the asp.net application. There were few requirements where we had to include a Pop up . This pop up is the Infragistics Web Dialog window. When there is a postback on page I get the "Pkease Wait" but when there is a postback on Pop up - The "please wait" div is always behind the pop up and User cannot see. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to change its `z-index` to the maximum `z-index` value to ensure its on the top.

Comment: I am using the following CSS for the "Please Wait" div. Can you tell me what is wrong in this one?   .opaqueLayer
{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 opacity: 0.4;
 filter: alpha(opacity=40);
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 z-index: 1000;
}

Comment: Whats the z-index of the div that comes infront of 'please wait' div?

Comment: Wheres the CSS of 'please wait' div? I still cant find it.

Comment: From ViewSource see that webDialogWinow is taking it as 100000. and CSS for Please wait div .questionLayer
{
 position: absolute;
 height: 2px;
 display: none;
 z-index: 1001;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-color: #D3D3D3;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-bottom: 4%;
 padding-top: 1%;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 font-size: medium;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: Black;
}

Comment: The div that you want to put on top of everything, its z index has to be the largest.